# Añadir variables a URL en Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, formularios, url, urlencoding

La función `Request::fullUrl()` devuelve la URL entera actual, con todo y variables GET:

`https://www.fakesite.test/about/results?cat_id=327&city_id=46`

¿Cómo puedo a través de JavaScript, añadir más variables a esa URL, pudiendo quedar más o menos así:

`https://www.fakesite.test/about/results?cat_id=327&city_id=46&person_id=445&lat=6.3442342&lon=-7.34224332`

La URL con  `Request::fullUrl()` ya la estoy usando como el atributo action de un form, pero debo poder añadirle más variables.

Comment: ¿Habra algun momento en que la url no tenga variables antes de que la edites?

Comment: No Jonathan. Siempre va a contener por lo menos una

Comment: Imagino que usas esto en blade `action="{{ Request::fullUrl() }}"`, de ser asi, solo concatena el texto con `&var=value`

Comment: muéstranos que has intentado y cuales problemas problemas/errores te encontraste